# Difficulties in styling GWT interfaces

Tags: java, css, gwt, user-interface

I am getting in styling gwt existing widgets such as decorated panel, how to change the colors of the borders from blue to another color or the stack panel, how to change the color of the header. Does someone know how to fully customise the widgets or panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default styles applied to GWT widgets are listed in the [API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/index.html?overview-summary.html). Take a look at the [`DecoratedStackPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedStackPanel.html). There you'll see the following styles listed:

- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel { the panel
  itself }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .gwt-StackPanelItem { unselected
  items }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .gwt-StackPanelItem-selected {
  selected items }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .gwt-StackPanelContent { the wrapper
  around the contents of the item }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopLeft { top left corner
  of the item}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopLeftInner { the inner
  element of the cell}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopCenter { top center of
  the item}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopCenterInner { the inner
  element of the cell}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopRight { top right corner
  of the item}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemTopRightInner { the inner
  element of the cell}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleLeft { left side of
  the item }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleLeftInner { the inner
  element of the cell}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleCenter { center of
  the item, where the item text resides
  }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleCenterInner { the
  inner element of the cell}
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleRight { right side of
  the item }
- .gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .stackItemMiddleRightInner { the
  inner element of the cell}

In order to overwrite one of these styles remember to declare your definition as `@external` to make sure it is not being obfuscated (see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes)).

Answer (score 1):

GWT themes are injected via the theme modules. They can be found in the `com.google.gwt.user.theme package`. For example to include the standard add the following inherits:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.StandardResources"/>
```

You can create your own custom styling by creating a similar module. Simply copy the content of one of the standards theme's and create your own gwt module and add you inherit to your module.

To make things more easier this theme generator: http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/ generates both the CSS and the images for the GWT style. This should help you get a quick start. It contains the `.gwt-Decorated` style.